# errors in project but none in source files

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with Android ADT plugin and my source file will not compile due to errors in project. There are no errors marked anywhere in any of the files in the project. I've tried using clean before compiling but no luck. Is it a case of re-installing Eclipse to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the errors? Can you post the first few errors and the code that causes them? It might give a hint as to what the problem is...

Comment: ok thanks. When i clean the project i get the following error in the console. have you any ideas? [2011-01-29 18:26:50 - recorder] 1 error; aborting [2011-01-29 18:26:50 - recorder] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 –

Answer (score 2):

This might be Due to the Problem or Error in a another project source that you are  using (build Path) For an Ex

if you use A project to the B project   if the Project A contain any error it 'll  effect on your B project then it Shows that message Though it does'nt  have an error

Answer (score 0):

Is `gen/R.java` generated?

If not, you may have errors in `res` dir.
Sometimes the console tab shows useful hints about that.

Possible fixes:

-Reset the path to the Android SDK.

-Check if all libraries are on place

-Clear the project and try to rebuild

-Refresh the project

-Check the Console tab - sometimes the root of all problems is shown there.

-Check if there is some problems in the res dir, sometimes gen/R.java could't be build because of that

Comment: ok thanks. When i clean the project i get the following error in the console. have you any ideas? [2011-01-29 18:26:50 - recorder] 1 error; aborting
[2011-01-29 18:26:50 - recorder] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just right click the error in your problems window and press delete. This is a bug with Eclipse, where it doesn't realise the error has gone.

Comment: Yeah, thanks the downvoting a year old reply to an issue that solved it for the poster anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently added any resources check try removing them. Sometimes if I add things that are in a format it doesnt like it doesnt really tell me why its failing but that is why. Also i occasionally have it think there is still an error even after i fixed whatever was wrong. To fix this I felete the project from my workspace and then import it back in, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the "Properties" of your project. You might find something like "5 build path entries are missing". This will show up as an error on the project but not on the source files.

I got this error when I had references to .jar files that I later deleted/moved.

Answer (score 0):

u can have a check on resources file and also drawable folder....none of file names are capital....also see u have put png file in drawable not jpg...

Answer (score 0):

1.just remove android .jar from your build path and other . jar files

2.clean the project

3.some times now you can run the project

4.if not add those removed external libraries and run again ,

thats it :D

Answer (score 0):

First try the clean 
if it does not work close the eclipse and reopen the application
if it also does not work download and install the latest java SDK
It should solve the problem